# How do query all documents of a collection in Fire Store

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to display information from Cloud Firestore on Google maps. I am able to apply a marker from a document using the below code, however I have multiple documents that I need to display the data from.

Below is the current code and as I said it successfully displays a marker with info from one document, however every document contains a different location that needs to be displayed on the map.

```
    private void addMapMarkers(){

    FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    CollectionReference pointsRef = rootRef.collection("notes");
    DocumentReference docRef = pointsRef.document("u20UmWSrlP0EiZH9CNP3");
    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new 
    OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {
                    String latitude = document.getString("Latitude");
                    String longitude = document.getString("Longitude");
                    String name = document.getString("Attraction Name");

                    float lat = Float.parseFloat(latitude);
                    float lng = Float.parseFloat(longitude);

                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                    mMaps.addMarker(new 
                    MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(name));
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Database Structure like below :

[image]

Comment: Have you reviewed the documentation on how to perform a query?  Is there something that's unclear with respect to that documentation?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: @DougStevenson I have looked at that, but I am still unable to complete my code. It shows how to query for specific things. But I am still unsure on how to search the field of multiple documents like I asked.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection

Comment: Personally, I think the documentation is fairly clear if you go over things from the beginning.  Is there a particular part of it that you're having problems with?  What you're asking isn't a very common question.

Comment: @DougStevenson Unfortuantely what you have sent me has just confused me more. I am just trying to amend the code so it reads all documents in the collection, rather than just one document like it currently does.

Comment: You should be careful while posting the firebase cloud details, you should try to hide the console url for security purpose. just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the values of your `latitude` and `longitude` properties of all documents, simply use the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference notesRef = rootRef.collection("notes");
notesRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                float lat = Float.parseFloat(document.getString("Latitude"));
                float lng = Float.parseFloat(document.getString("Longitude"));
                String name = document.getString("Attraction Name");
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                mMaps.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(name));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

So the key for solving this problem is the use of `task.getResult()` that can help you iterate through the `QueryDocumentSnapshot` object.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out

Comment: Ok and keep me posted.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to all document data you can try this:-

```
db.collection("Chat").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                for (DocumentChange dc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                    switch (dc.getType()) {
                        case ADDED:
                            //  Log.d("TAG", "New Msg: " + dc.getDocument().toObject(Message.class));

                            break;
                        case MODIFIED:

                            //      Log.d("TAG", "Modified Msg: " + dc.getDocument().toObject(Message.class));
                            break;
                        case REMOVED:
                            //     Log.d("TAG", "Removed Msg: " + dc.getDocument().toObject(Message.class));
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```